# vb.net creating a square to show a color selected by a color dialog

Tags: vb.net, colordialog

I want to have a little square that will display the color currently selected by a color dialog.

It should look like this: [Picture of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCyDJ.jpg)

And the green box, should update to another color when they choose one.
How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Using colorDialog As New ColorDialog
    'If the user actually selected a color Then
    If colorDialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        'Set the background color of the picture box = color selected from the color dialog
        PictureBox1.BackColor = colorDialog.Color
    End If
End Using
```

Place this code in your `Button_Click` event handler.